# Como relacionar 2 arrays (array1 é nome e array2 é ID) e trazer o valor correspondente

Tags: php, array

Tenho 2 arrays, onde uma é um array com os nomes e a outra é um array com os ids. Preciso que conforme o nome da string (que contém na array $nome), ele busque na array id, o id correspondente, ex:

```
$nome=array('a','b','c');
$id=array('1','2','3');
$caracnome='b';
```

Aí preciso, nesse exmplo, trazer por exemplo a variavel `$caracid = '2'`, porque 'b' é o segundo valor do array $nome e o segundo valor do array $id é 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem a função [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-combine.php) do php que combina um array com outro fazendo com que o primeiro array passe a ser as chaves e o segundo os valores. Para o seu código associar as duas coisas permite-lhe facilmente saber qual o id associado a um determinado nome.

Utilizar o `array_combine` seria assim:

```
$nomesIds = array_combine($nome, $id);
```

O que fica neste `$nomesIds` é:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
)
```

Por isso para obter o `id` do `b` basta:

```
$caracid = $nomesIds[$caracnome];
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/21K1xM)

Comment: show, valeu, isso mesmo!!